# Pricelist how to store in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need to store a pricelist in the database.

What is the best way to store a pricelist?

Example of the pricelist:

[image]

I have thinked of 2 solutions.

Create a table named products, with the columns:

```
name (varchar)
price (integer)
price_2 (integer)
```

The name would then be example for example be "product_a1" used to refer to the YAML translation file.

And then create all the name of the products. So example in my case there would be about 100.

Solution 2:

Store all the data in one row. So the table columns would be:

```
product_a1
product_a2
product_a3
product_b1
product_b1_2
product_b2
product_b2_2
```

and 99 more..

PS: I have only 1 pricelist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the [Entity–attribute–value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) (EAV), this way you can get as many attributes on your model as you want. It gives you great flexibility, so in the future you can add more attributes dynamically without refactoring your code.

Comment: EAV is a lot similar to solution 1 I guess ?

Comment: Not really. You creating another table column instead of a table with properties (id, description, attribute, value) and later associate a property with your product model. It's an one-to-many relationship between product and properties.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create two tables with a relationship between them:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prices
end
```

and

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: :product
end
```

This gives you the flexibility to add additional prices in the future if necessary.  I'm loath to hardcode databases with fixed limits.

Comment: It's not all that hard to avoid setting up that hardcoded limitation.  If you're sure about doing so then I'd go with solution #1, but under duress. :)